# Keras: unable to use GPU to its full capacity

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

When I run my code, I get this message every time:

```
2018-09-27 19:31:03.353933: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 650 Ti major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.941
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.65GiB
2018-09-27 19:31:03.355743: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-27 19:31:04.822514: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-27 19:31:04.822895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-09-27 19:31:04.823072: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
2018-09-27 19:31:04.823679: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1416 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0)
2018-09-27 19:31:12.050251: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 261.79MiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2018-09-27 19:31:17.191146: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.13GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

The last 2 messages, which are warnings, seem odd to me: I supposedly have 1.65GiB of free memory, yet some smaller amounts cannot be allocated. **What could I do to fix it? What is the source of this message?** But also: why can't I get more than 50% usage from my GPU ?

Here is what it looks like when I start training:

[image: Initialization of training]

The code itself is in [my repo](https://github.com/payne911/SR-ResCNN-Keras-) (it's hard for me to know which parts of my code are relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not using a multi-gpu model?

see for example https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/30/how-to-multi-gpu-training-with-keras-python-and-deep-learning/

Comment: But I only have 1 GPU. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the batch size? I see from your code that you use `batch size = 1`

Comment: Using a bigger batch size causes `OOM Exception` on my GPU. But it's surprising since I'm clearly far from using it all with a single image being processed.